# Django web application -- how to access local harddrive?

Tags: django, client-side

I know how to access the local harddrive using a signed applet, but I am developing a new web application in Django that also needs this functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the hard drive on the browser, it isn't a Django question at all, since Django is only on the server.  You need to find a client-side way to get at what you need.  A signed applet would work in a Django application just as well as any other server-side technology.

Comment: What would other options be? Flash?